# Solving for function f and constant c using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus with x^2 instead of x

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The question says:

Find a function f and a constant C such that

$$
\int_1^{x^2}f(t)dt = x^3+C\qquad\text{ for } x>0
$$

I've tried using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and taking the derivative  on both sides and leaves:

$$
f(x^2)2x=3x^2
$$

$$
f(x^2)=\frac32x
$$

Assuming this is the right way to start, I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Just change $x$ by $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: Yeah you're right, just did it. I can't believe it was that easy. I'm feeling dumb now.

Comment: A notes about MathJax: use it also in the title. To write small bits of text inside the math mode use text  ( in your case `\text{ for }` ). To add spaces use `x \, y` $x \, y$, `x \; y` $x \; y$, `x \quad y` $x \quad y$, `x \qquad y` $x \qquad y$